# Sharing properties between bootstrap configurations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

**Problem:**

I have two libraries whose purpose is to take properties from their respective sources and provide them to my application at startup. Currently both libraries provide their own `PropertySourceLocator`s as a part of their `BootstrapConfiguration`.

(Just as described here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-commons/1.3.3.RELEASE/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#customizing-bootstrap-property-sources)

E.g.

- libraryX is responsible for getting properties from SourceX and configuring a respective PropertySourceLocator.
- libraryY is responsible for getting properties from SourceY and configuring a respective PropertySourceLocator

These libraries are configured at my `bootstrap.yaml`. E.g.

```
libX.enabled: true
libX.password: ${LIB_X_PASS}

libY.enabled: true
libY.password: ${LIB_Y_PASS}
```

Everything works great as long as these libraries don't use properties from one another.

Unfortunately, in my case libX should be a source of ${LIB_Y_PASS}.

So the `bootstrap.yaml` is now looking something like this:

```
libX.enabled: true
libX.password: ${LIB_X_PASS}

libY.enabled: true
libY.password: ${libX.values.lib_y_pass}
```

In this configuration application no longer starts since resolution of ${LIB_X_PASS} and ${libX.values.lib_y_pass} happens before `PropertySourceLocator`s are called.

**Potential solutions:**

1. Use `@PropertySource` instead of `PropertySourceLocator` at `libX`.

Values provided by `@PropertySource`s seem to be available at the moment when resolution of properties in `bootstrap.yaml` is happening. The only issue is, is that it seems to have the same priority with other `application*.yaml`/`application*.properties` files, located in the project. So it is impossible to override existing properties with something that will come from `libX`.
E.g.

```
libX.enabled: true
libX.password: ${LIB_X_PASS}

libY.enabled: true
libY.password: ${libX.values.lib_y_pass}
libX.values.lib_y_pass: dummy_password
```

`libY.password` will have `dummy_password` value instead of whatever comes from `libX` `@PropertySource`. Possible reason for that is the fact that `bootstrap.yaml` as propertySource comes before the property source libX created and during resolution spring picks the value from the first propertySource that has it.

2. Use `org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor`

We can inject libX property source as first property source during environment post processing phase.
E.g.

```
@Override
public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
                                   SpringApplication application) {

    ....
    environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(libxPropertySource);
}
```

This seems to work fine and fixes the problem from the solution#1, but I don't know if there are hidden problems that I haven't found yet.

**Question**

Are there better ways to approach the problem?

It seems like either:
A) My case (when I need properties from one bootstrap `PropertySourceLocator` in another) goes against the design of `PropertySourceLocator` and in this case hacks like these is the only way.
B) I'm missing something and the problem can be solved in an much easier way.

Comment: This is a limitation of bootstrap. This changes with boot 2.4.0 config file processing as the environment will be cumulative. https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4

Comment: Hey @spencergibb.  Thanks for your comment. I've tried to reimplement the same example using 2020.0.0-M4 spring cloud version and it seems to have the same problem. Could you please explain what changes have to be made to make it work with this new version of the library? This is the same example in github https://github.com/kotovdv/bootstrap-shared-properties

Comment: I'm afraid it's more in depth than a stack over flow answer. It doesn't use bootstrap or PropertySourceLocator but the new spring boot `ConfigData` apis